# How to force 'function' to be an expression, not a statement?

Tags: javascript, webview

While this code is fine:

```
var x = function() { };
```

This code is not:

```
function() { };
```

The top example creates an anonymous function and assigns it to `x`. The bottom example is a *statement*, where a function name is required, so it is a syntax error.

Now, it may seem pointless to define an anonymous function and not assign it anywhere, but here's an example that confronts the behavior:

```
var x = eval('function() { }');
```

Which should behave just like the first example, but is a syntax error.

Deep in the app I'm working on, we come to this issue. I want `function() { }` to be an expression.

A short explanation why is that this is a native OSX app calling javascript into a `WebView`. We have an `evaluateJavascript` function which the native layer can use to call arbitrary javascript. `evaluateJavascript` wraps the given code with `try/catch` for error-handling, because it's the only way to get detailed error information. So if you call `myCallback = evaluateJavascript("function() { }")`, we generate a function with the following body:

```
try {
    return eval('function() { }');
} catch(e) {
    // ....
}
```

And return the result.

Comment: But why do you need a function to evaluate in the first place? Just evaluate the statements you would have had in the function?

Comment: The caller needs a function object returned.

Comment: Maybe this can help? [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)

Comment: @doldt hmm, good idea - just wrapping in parenthesis is OK to impose on the caller. Very elegant.

Comment: if you don't need closure (you probably don't/shouldn't), use Function() instead of eval()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When possible, don't use `eval`. Another option to find errors is if you listen for errors on the `window` (or equivalent) object and import the scripts as `<script>`s which are added and removed immediately.
2. Doing anything on the same line before `function` will cause `function` to be an expression

All of the following are valid (although useless)

```
0, function () {};
(function() {});
+function () {};
-function () {};
!function () {};
// etc
```

*Function expressions* like this are usually done for *IIFEs*, i.e.

```
(function (foo) {
    console.log(foo);
}('bar'));
// "bar" logged
```

But you can apply the style to your `eval`-ing. Either parenthesis or the comma operator should work for you

```
var code = 'function () {}';
var foo = eval('0, ' + code);
foo; // function () {}
```

Comment: I am using `window.onerror`, but this is not invoked for certain calls from native code. The incoming code doesn't necessarily need to be an expression; it can be any arbitrary JS. But with this, and the other answers, I think I have the solution. I think I will actually separate this into 2 different functions: `evaluateJSExpression` (with return val), and `evaluateJSCode` (no return val but it can be any block of js).

Answer (score 1):

Can't you do

`x = eval('y = function() {}')`

?

Answer (score 1):

**Attempt/Approach- 1 : Below should work**

```
var scope = {};
eval('scope.x = function() { return "Hello World"; }');
console.log(scope.x());
```

**Output**

```
Hello World
[Finished in 0.3s]
```

** **Approach - 2** **

After reading link on [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) insuggested in comments of above question, I tried below - and it seems to work as well.

```
var x = eval('(function() { return "Hello World"; })');
console.log(x());
```

However, I realized that with [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression), we need to have code like `(function(){})()` - note that trailing `()`.  However, in the Approach-2 code - I did not have the trailing `()`.  Then, I looked up the `eval` [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), and from it I came to know the following (which explains why Approach-2 works):

> eval as a string defining function requires "(" and ")" as prefix and
>   suffix

Comment: Hmm come to think of it, I guess expressions passed into my evaluateJavascript function cannot span multiple statements; they are expressions only. Thus I can get away with this. Or I think I prefer to wrap in parenthesis, as that should probably be done anyway.

Comment: Based on comments on your question about link to IIFE, parenethis approach seems elegant and right way

Answer (score 1):

You say `var x = eval('function() { }');` should behave just like the first example. Why do you think so? Your `eval` argument

```
function() { }
```

**is a statement** and invalid as you point out above. You could make it an expression like this:

```
var x = eval('(function() { })');
```